# Remove version number from jar in ant task

Tags: regex, ant

I'm trying to copy all JARs from one directory to another. During this process I want to remove version numbers at the end of the file names. (E.g. my-jar-1.2.3.jar to my-jar.jar)

I tried to wrap my head around mapper but I can't find a regexp to get that to work. I've tried this:

```
<copy todir="lib" flatten="true">
    <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)-[^.]*(\.jar)" to="\1\2" />
        <fileset dir="my.files.dir">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <type type="file" />
        </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THere's a mapper in the maven-ant-task-lib which does just that.

Answer (score 2):

here is a better version of the below answer:

```
<project>
    <mkdir dir="lib"/>
    <copy todir="lib"
        verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="jars/">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <mapper type="regexp"
            from="^(.+?)-[0-9]+.*\.jar$"
            to="\1.jar"/>
    </copy>
</project>
```

to handle "That last one is a trouble maker"

Answer (score 1):

This should work properly:

```
<copy todir="lib" flatten="true">
    <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)-[^-]*(\.jar)" to="\1\2" />
    <fileset dir="my.files.dir">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
        <type type="file" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<project>
    <mkdir dir="lib"/>
    <copy todir="lib"
        verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="jars/">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <mapper type="regexp"
            from="^(.+?)-[0-9].*$"
            to="\1.jar"/>
    </copy>
</project>
```

In a  `regex` mapper, the `from` parameter must match the entire name. I use the `+?` *non-greedy* pattern matcher. This matches the pattern of `.` which means *any character* but not greedily. Normally, this would match the entire line. However, I'm capturing up to the first time a dash followed by a number is found.

The problem happens if the jar has no version number, or it's starts with a non-numeric value. I can successfully, do these:

```
foo-2.3.2.jar
foo-2r1.jar
```

But not these:

```
foo-alpha.jar
foo.jar
```

So, I tweaked the pattern a bit:

```
<project>
    <mkdir dir="lib"/>
    <copy todir="lib"
        verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="jars/">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <mapper type="regexp"
            from="^(.+?)-[0-9]*.*\.jar$"
            to="\1.jar"/>
    </copy>
</project>

$ ant
    [mkdir] Created dir: lib
     [copy] Copying 5 files to lib
     [copy] Copying jars/bar-3.4.5.jar to lib/bar.jar
     [copy] Copying biff-86.4.2.jar to lib/biff.jar
     [copy] Copying jars/boff-2.31.2.jar to lib/boff.jar
     [copy] Copying jars/foo-1.2.3.jar tolib/foo.jar
     [copy] Copying jars/foo-bar-3.3.2.3.jar to lib/foo.jar
```

That last one is a trouble maker...

It might be worth doing this in two copies: One to take care if a version number is found, and a second to take care of jars without version numbers.